# display user input after pressing button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a total of 4 views. in view 1 the user inputs their first name then clicks a button to go into the next view

```
<lable for="fname">First Name</lable>
<asp:TextBox ID="fname" runat="server" required></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" style="color:red" ErrorMessage="* Letters Only" ControlToValidate="fname" ValidationExpression="^[aA-zZ]*$" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

i want to re-display the user's input on the 3rd view. this is my code for it

```
<asp:Label ID="cardName" runat="server" Text="Name On Card"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
```

vb for it

```
Private Sub View3_Activate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles View3.Activate
        Label1.Text = fname.Text
End Sub
```

this does not work, so i tried this

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Label1.Text = fname.Text
End Sub
```

(when button three is clicked, the page goes to view 3 from view 2. button type is not submit)

None of this has worked for me

Comment: Not an answer but you may want to change `lable`s

Comment: Could you show your full code? It looks like VB, not C#, but the last snippet is a mix of both. Other than the `lable` typo, and the mix of languages, your approach seems to be largely on the right track, so I suspect the answer lies outside the snippets shown here.

Comment: Do you want to see the aspx or the vb

Comment: Yeah, what language are you ACTUALLY trying to use? You can't intermix C# and VB.NET in the same code.

Comment: I'm trying to use vb

Comment: after you click on the button is there anything in `fname` TextBox? according to your question it may empty. so you have to store the value temporarily or should surrounded that control by an update pannel

Comment: @meadwho Preferably both, but certainly the aspx file for starters...

Answer (score 2):

You can use ASP.NET `Session` to store the value the user entered and then pull that value out of `Session` when you want to display it on view 3.

In button click event handler on view 1, do this:

```
Protected Sub View1_ButtonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Session("FirstName") = fname.Text
End Sub
```

Now in the `Page_Load` of view 3, do this:

```
Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ' Get first name value out of Session by name here and set label
    Label1.Text = Session("FirstName").ToString()
End Sub
```

**Note** - Things you put into `Session` are of type `Object` so you must cast the value to the correct type. In this case, the `.ToString()` makes it a `String` that can be put as the text of the label.